# Set up google sheet to protect previous rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set up a sheet for about 50 users. 
Each user is supposed to put in information in about 5 undetermined rows (usually under the last row). 
Rows should only be edible by the creator of the rows and the owner of the sheet

This can be done by google script, right? I have never coded before, so im completely overwhelmed with the possibilities of google script.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: I'd use a different sheet for each user.  You can always combine them into a master sheet whenever you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Protection class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) for apps script, it can help you create the rules you want. The approach you could follow is to have an `onEdit()` function ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)) which, when the user writes into one of the rows, uses the `Protection` class to make the user the only one with permision to edit those rows. You will need the user's email which you can get with `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();` ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser)).

Since you mention you're new to Apps Script, I recommend you take a look at the [Sheets guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), it will tell you the basics of how to work with Spreadsheets through Apps Script. Mixing that guide with the other documentation should put you in the right track to get what you want.